# Combine string lights with lamp bulb?

Tags: wiring, led, lamp

Is it possible to combine 5 watt electric LED string lights with E26LED lamp socket to be powered with a single switch?  The hope is to use a single switch to light up the planets (string lights) and the sun (E26 bulb).  Have very little experience.  Alternate ideas welcomed & thank you in advance.

[image: Please see attached]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

PLUTO ADDED.  :)
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPGIr.png

Comment: They forgot Pluto.  I did not spend years in school learning Pluto is a planet to have it taken away.  If the switch is on the light, you just plug it in.  If no switch on the light you will need a switched outlet.

Comment: Pluto added.  Thank you; the 7-yo would have been disappointed!

Comment: FYI, if it is more convenient, you can find 12v e26 bulbs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both the string lights and the bulb are made to run off 110V (US) and both are made to plug into a standard outlet then YES !

You didn't indicate if you had a switched outlet or something set up for this.

If you don't and need direction to make a switched outlet, let us know. or you can purchase a [UL listed switched power strip](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DOMYL24)

Comment: The US is standard 120v these days.  Some people are picky about it, some just eh close enough.

Comment: Appreciate the guidance; this is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you for taking the time.